# onCLick getElementById().innerHTML doesn't work repeatedly?

Tags: input, onclick, innerhtml

here is the page on which the problem lies: www.hodaradesign.com/vis-vertical2.html

I tried to enter code here but the site wouldn't let me. So go to the page and view source. There is a list of 10 inputs. three dont work even though all 10 inputs use the same code.
can anyone help me out?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML code you use for "Light n Life" there is a sentence: "LNL's founder wanted a logo [...]". It contains a single quote ("LNL's") which ends the string. You have to escape single quotes.